# Laravel select tags in edit page

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-chosen

I cannot get assigned tags in my view as auto selected:

**Logic**

1. Get all tags `$tags`.
2. Get assigned tags from database `$tags2`.
3. Auto select assigned tags.

## Code

```
<select class="chosen-select-tags" name="tags[]" multiple id="tags">
  @foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <option value="{{$tag->id}}"
      // selecting old tags
      @foreach($tags2 as $tt)
       {{ $tag->id == $tt ? 'selected' : '' }}
      @endforeach
      // end of selecting old tags
    >{{$tag->title}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

`Values`

`$tags` array of assigned tags to my model in this case 2, `result`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "40b7ea5f-a2d8-4b4e-af6c-b023c2b75db3"
  1 => "533c66f6-073b-4342-8fb1-ec5ede3a0c9c"
]
```

this two `uuid` should be auto selected in `$tags` which is is my full tags array.

`Current result`

[image: one]

Nothing has been selected.

**Note: I am using [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) for my select input**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `in_array()`

ref link https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

```php
<select class="chosen-select-tags" name="tags[]" multiple id="tags">
    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <option value="{{$tag->id}}" {{ in_array($tag->id,$tag2) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$tag->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: didn't work :/ maybe not bad idea to mention that i'm using [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) for my select input.

Comment: @mafortis this library is Deprecated  i recommend to use  https://select2.org/

Comment: yeah deprecated means it doesn't get more updates but the current functionality still work just fine plus select2 won't go with my design and it'll require more work to fix it's css for my template.

Comment: @mafortis i have read the doc and didn't find to set default value

Comment: guess what? :D all I had to do was to clear my cache and your code worked just fine LOL